# Resistance is futile

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Resistance is futile
>
> ---
>
> When analysing the Borg genome, Banfield and colleagues also saw features suggesting that Borgs have assimilated genes from diverse sources, including the main Methanoperedens chromosome, Banfield says. This potential to ‘assimilate’ genes led her son to propose the name ‘Borg’ over Thanksgiving dinner in 2020.
> Source: [Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-01947-3)

Whose "Resistance is futile"? This subtitle of the article is not clear to me. From the context, it seems to say that the Borgs' power of assimilating other genes is so strong that resistance against it by the genes assimilated appears to be in vain/futile. I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the fictional tv show "Star Trek", the Borg are a race that assimilate other species, making them into new Borg.  When they meet people they say

> Resistance is futile. You will be assimilated.

The article is about a type of DNA structure that is named after this fictional race. The section heading is just quoting Star Trek.  It means "Resistance to the Borg is futile", or perhaps it is suggesting that borg based DNA techologoy will be "as successful as CRISPR", but the only reason for this phrasing is the quote from Star Trek.